# Copy file in share point at a particular location using latest graph api and java

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I was using the old version of Graph API library (5.77.0) and used the below code to copy files to share point. This way I did not have to know the drive ID before hand and I could copy the file to the location as per the business logic. The logic was to copy the same path as source of the file (source is a different system) and adding date folder in the beginning.  e.g. if the source is Folder1/Folder2/file.txt the destination in share point needs to be YYYYMMDD/Folder1/Folder2/file_timestamp.txt

```
graphServiceClient.sites(site_id).drive().root().itemWithPath(destination).content().buildRequest().put(fileStream.readAllBytes());
```

With the new version I am not able to figure out how can I copy as above as root method is no longer there. Please advice how can copy by still keeping the destination as per business logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SDK v6, it's not straightforward as it used to be in v5.

Some major changes:

- get root => `graphClient.drives().byDriveId("id").items().byDriveItemId("root").get()`
- get item by path => `graphClient.drives().byDriveId("id").items().byDriveItemId("root:/path_to_file:").get()`

To upload a file content with SDK v6

```
// first get drive of a site
Drive drive = graphServiceClient.sites().bySiteId(site_id).drive().get();

// use drive id
// specify path to the destination item in byDriveItemId
graphServiceClient.drives().byDriveId(drive.getId()).items().byDriveItemId("root:/YYYYMMDD/Folder1/Folder2/file_timestamp.txt:").content().put(fileStream);
```